# How do you Associate/Dissociate an HTS token using EVM transaction?

Tags: solidity, hedera-hashgraph

Before I can receive an HTS token I need to first associate with the token ID.
If I were using the JS SDK I know to do the following where the `accountId` is the account that I want to associate with the token.

```
  const associateTransaction = await new TokenAssociateTransaction()
    .setAccountId(accountId)
    .setTokenIds([tokenId])
    .freezeWith(client);
```

However, how do you Associate/Dissociate an HTS token using an EVM transaction?

I’ve attempted to do the following in my smart contract

```
function mintNft(
        address token,
        bytes[] memory metadata
    ) public payable returns(int64){

        (int response, , int64[] memory serial) = HederaTokenService.mintToken(token, 0, metadata);
        if(response != HederaResponseCodes.SUCCESS){
            revert("Failed to mint non-fungible token");
        }

        int res = HederaTokenService.associateToken(
            address(msg.sender),
            token
        );

        if(res != HederaResponseCodes.SUCCESS){
            revert("Failed to associate non-fungible token");
        }
        
        return serial[0];
    }
```

However, when I try to transfer the contract reverts with the following error:

```
TOKEN_NOT_ASSOCIATED_TO_ACCOUNT
```

I’d like to be able to do so within a smart contract deployed to HSCS, preferably. If that is not possible, is there another way to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `associateToken` on  `HederaTokenService` System Contract  is deprecated and can no longer associate to `address(msg.sender)`. It can only associate to `address(this)`. The user must call the associate function on the token's contract directly.

Smart Contracts cannot change an externally owned accounts state meaning a contract cannot associate, transfer, and approve transaction on a users behalf. Although highly useful, by allowing a contract to change an EOA state it could potentially allow a bad actor to act maliciously on behalf of a user. Therefore, Associating/disassociating HTS tokens within smart contracts is not allowed. You can read further about the security update to smart contracts [here](https://hedera.com/blog/hedera-smart-contract-service-security-model-update).

I will show you how to associate/dissociate using ethers.js

You first start by setting up your ethers provider, requesting access to accounts, and getting your signer.

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");
await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
```

Next you will construct the `abi` which species the contract function you want to execute

```
const abi = ["function associate()"];
```

You can can treat HTS tokens as if they were ERC20/ERC721 tokens. This functionality is what allows us to call the `associate`/`dissociate` function directly on the HTS token. In order to do so, you must first convert the HTS tokenID into it’s solidity address with a ‘0x’ prefix.

```
const tokenSolidityAddress = '0x' + TokenId.fromString('0.0.572609').tokenSolidityAddress();
```

Finally, create a contract instance and call associate directly on the contract.

```
// create contract instance using token solidity address, abi, and signer
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(tokenSolidityAddress, abi, signer);

  try {
    const transactionResult = await contract.associate();
    return transactionResult.hash;
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error.message ? error.message : error);
    return null;
  }
```

How to dissociate an HTS token:

```
async function dissociateToken() {
    // set up your ethers provider
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");
    // request access to the user's account
    await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
    // get signer
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const abi = ["function dissociate()"];
    const tokenSolidityAddress = '0x' + TokenId.fromString('0.0.572609').tokenSolidityAddress();
    // create contract instance using token solidity address, abi, and signer
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(tokenSolidityAddress, abi, signer);
  
    try {
      const transactionResult = await contract.dissociate();
      return transactionResult.hash;
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error.message ? error.message : error);
      return null;
    } 
};
```